# How to validate OPC UA Node Items?

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

Lets say, I have Node1 and Node2 in OPC UA server and its corresponding node ID will be ns=2;i=100 and ns=2;i=101.

Assume that I want to configure these items in a UI(Node Name and Node ID). How to validate the Node Name and the Node ID entered by the user is correct?

Is there any simpler way to do it?

**My Analysis:** We can create a subscription and add these Nodes as a monitored items to the subscription. In that results, we can see if the Node ID is valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a subscription and monitored items. Just use the Read service to read the BrowseName, DisplayName, Value, and/or whatever other attributes you're interested in.

If the NodeId is invalid or doesn't exist the server will return a StatusCode indicating so. Otherwise you'll get the values for the attributes you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Trying manually different IDs and wait for the returned StatusCode can be very frustrating for the user .... a kind of blind selection.

The right way for me is to implement in your software some way to navigate through the node tree and then the user can directly select the nodes. Take a look to OPC UA **Browse** service.